# «Год» и «лето» — этимология

Tags: этимология

31 декабря я была на новогодней службе.
Так вот, наш митрополит поздравлял всех не с *Новым годом*, а с *Новолетием*.
И действительно, если посмотреть, слово "год" в старых текстах как-то и не звучит. *Многие лета, в лето такое-то* и т. д.
То есть выходит, что слово "год" появилось в русском языке недавно?
И если так, откуда оно в языке взялось и зачем заменило слово "лето"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, разумеется. "Лето" - слово древнее, общеславянское, "год" - в этом значении недавнее, хотя само по себе едва ли не древнее слова "лето".

Перво-наперво."Новолетие" обычная форма для языка клириков. Тут не стоит искать каких-то глубинных мотивов или фактов. Чтобы поставить вопрос ребром, достаточно рассмотреть вполне гражданские понятия "один год" и "пять лет".

Какого ...летия "наш митрополит" поздравляет с католическим новым годом - вопрос тоже интересный, но это не здесь.

Причины такого изменения названия дискуссионны. Я очень кратко. Видимо, в праславянском языке "год" обозначало "время" вообще или некий отрезок его. Об этом говорит то, что в разных славянских год и производные могут означать разные единицы времени. Одной из таких единиц стал календарный год. Со временем это значение было вытеснено (или почти вытеснено) таким же общеславянским "лето" - оно тоже имело два значения (год и время года, а возможно и третье - "время", т.е. было почти полным синонимом года), но на первом этапе в меньшей степени могло породить путаницу. Поскольку годы считали по сезонам ("летам"), то замена получилась естественной и понятной.

Но с развитием представлений о календаре и сущности года как смены сезонов, уже слово "лето" стало порождать двусмысленность. Ну а с утратой значения год=время, год стал активно восстанавливать значение основной единицы календарного цикла.
Но это уже в эпоху раздельного существования славянских языков. В большинстве славянских "год" восходит к "рок", а производные от "года" - означают "час" или время вообще.

Answer (score 0):

О том, почему произошёл переход от лет к годам с уважаемым behemothusом я соглашусь, добавив, что произошло это в 17-м веке, но позволю себе выразить другую версию относительно происхождения года. **Год** созвучно слову **ход** - ход времени. Но это не просто ход времени, а его цикличный отрезок - временной шаг. Но как связать год и шаг? Всё просто, если вспомнить, что в украинском и белорусском языках шаг - крок, хода, а год - рок. Краткий отрезок - крок, определённый - срок, цикличный - рок. Известно так же ранее употребляемое слово година - час, ныне сохранившееся в вышеуказанных языках. Я пытался осмыслить и известную версию о происхождении года от годити, но там такие дебри... Хотя и интересно - [link text](http://shmess.do.am/news/interesnoe_proiskhozhdenie_slov_o_proiskhozhdenii_privychnykh_slov/2014-03-27-15).