# Происхождение слова "Год"

Tags: история

Был похожий вопрос [Год и лето](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/45084/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE).

В Лето 7208 от СМЗХ Пётр 1 запретил старое летоисчисление, а вместе с ним и русский календарь (Коляды Даръ) и ввёл григорианский западно-европейский календарь от Рождества Христова. Он перенёс начало календаря с Дня Осеннего Равноденствия (у Славян-Староверов) и 1 сентября (у христиан) на 1 Генваря, и обозначил начальную дату — 1700 год.

25 декабря христианский мир отмечает Рождество Христово. А согласно Библии, на восьмой день младенец Исус был обрезан по иудейскому обряду, т.е. 1 Генваря христианской церковью отмечалось Обрезание Господне. Вот эту дату и выбрал Петр 1. Своим указом он велел всем подданным отмечать начало нового календаря и поздравлять друг-друга с Новым Годом.

При дворе Петра 1 на русском языке почти не разговаривали (он считался языком простого народа), а всё общение шло в основном на немецком и голландском языках. Слово Год (God) на этих языках, означает Бог. Т.е. своим указом Пётр заставил подданных поздравлять друг друга с Новым Богом в день его обрезания. Эта петрова шутка существует до сих пор, и люди, потеряв изначальный смысл, продолжают 1 января поздравлять друг друга с Новым обрезанным Богом, а не с Новолетием, как это было раньше…

Действительно ли слово "год" происходит от западноевропейского "god"?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, это не так.

- > Год. Это общеславянское существительное связано с глаголом годити в
  > значении «приспособлять», «прилаживать». Изначальный смысл слова год —
  > «нечто прилаженное, желанное», «то, что годится; это подтверждается и
  > другими славянскими языками, в которых однокоренные году
  > существительные до сих пор сохраняют такое значение, как, например, в
  > польском, где gody означает «пир», «праздник» **(Этимологический словарь Крылова)**.
- > Год. Редко кому приходит в голову связывать между собою такие слова, как
  > «год», «погода», «выгода», «угодье», а между тем все они близкие
  > родичи. Корень у всех один, общеславянский. «Год» значило некогда
  > «хорошее», «подходящее». Что — хорошее? Всё, в том числе и «хорошее
  > время», «подходящее время». В иных славянских языках и сейчас «god»,
  > «hod» означает «пир», «праздник» **(Этимологический словарь Успенского)**.
- > Год Общеслав. Производное от годити «удовлетворять, подходить».
  > Первоначально — «подходящее время», затем — «время» (вообще) и далее —
  > «365 дней». В последнем значении — собств. рус. Родственно нем. gut
  > «хороший», латышск. gods «праздник» < «хорошее время» и др.
  > **(Этимологический словарь Шанского)**.

Английское же God пришло из староанглийского, а там появилось из прагерманского языка (*guthan). Родственными также являются: древнесаксонский, древнефризский, голландский – god, немецкий Gott, старонорвежский – guð, готический – guþ, от праиндоевропейского *ghut – «тот, кому молятся». Для сравнения: старославянский zovo «звать», санскрит huta – «молиться». Все эти слова происходят от общего корня *gheu(e) – «звать, поклоняться» **(по материалам статьи "Этимология английских идиом и фразеологизмов тематической группы «религия»")**.

Кстати, *календарь* происходит от лат. calendarium (буквально — "долговая книга"), а то — от calendae "календы"; это были первые числа каждого месяца в римском календаре, в это время должники платили проценты.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132652/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid---).